# Developer.Twitter is not loading full page/css, not able to create app

Tags: javascript, php, twitter

I am developing web application for which i need to implement twitter login with PHP.
So, following Twitter Documentation and GoogleSearch, first i need to create app on https://apps.twitter.com/

But the problem is All app.twiiter.com page/css are not loading full.
Check out the following screenshot of my browser :

[image]

And also mainly, while creating an app same problem persist, even after inserting app details: name description etc. and after submitting, it shows an error "The form has become outdated. Copy any unsaved work in the form below and then reload this page."

Check out following screenshot of my browser :

[image]

I tried every single browser, but having same issue.
Am i the only one facing the problem ?Or twitter's developer page is having issues? Please Help.

Comment: Just 5 Minutes before I've created an application in Twitter apps page. Yes, alignments are not good in some parts. But, i can able to create an app. `OS` - Ubuntu, `Browser` - Chrome.

Comment: @YuvaRaj i am still facing the same problem, OS - MAC OS X 10.8.5

Comment: Try with some other browser.

Comment: I tried every major browsers , Chrome,FireFox,Safari,IE

Comment: I have also tried in every browser but not able to generate key's